# How to send GCM device token to IBM Bluemix

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I am getting device token from GCM. But in IBM Bluemix Cordova documentation,they are never sending Device Token.
Then how will the device will be registered in Bluemix for individual push notification.
Link to Cordova Blemix Doc - [DOCUMENTATION](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/enablepush_cordova.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you register the device with the Bluemix Push service, the success message returned will contain the Device ID.

```
var success = function(message) { console.log("Success: " + message); };
var failure = function(message) { console.log("Error: " + message); };
MFPPush.registerDevice({}, success, failure);
```

Is that what you mean by Device Token?

**Update**

The GCM service provides the Device token which the SDK validates and updates with the Bluemix Push service.

You can find more details and an extensive timeline outlining the process @ https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-cordova-plugin-push

Scroll down to "Push Notification SDK flows for hybrid Android Apps"